# viewDidLoad not called when using a WatchOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch, watchos

I am finalising a watchOS App, but am having difficulties to get the iPhone App to work when the watchApp has made a request.

It seems that the App loads in the background on the data request from the Apple Watch. However, if I then (within the time the App is still in the background) open the App the view is showing, but without going through the normal initiation like calling viewDidLoad.

How can I properly load the view in this case, when I launch the App when already loaded through an external process like the Apple Watch?

The reason I need to initialise the view is because it is populated by the database.

[edit:]
The Application is a normal Storyboard application. The initial view controller is a UINavigationController which loads an UIViewController as rootViewController.

This is done 'automatic' by the specification in the Ap settings. My feeling is that because the storyboard seems to be loaded in the background the RootViewController class is not loaded for some reason.

Comment: I know this is a work around, but how about using applicationDidBecomeActive or applicationWillEnterForeground? The question is do those get called.

Comment: They do. I was then thinking to sent a notification, but I have no way to initialise them.

Comment: You should provide more information about the navigation architecture. Like how do you initialize your view controller, how do you present it on screen, etc.

Comment: I added some information regarding the view controller structure.

Comment: Have you tried checking viewWillAppear?

Comment: As far as I can tell non of the functions (viewViewLoad, viewWillAppear etc) are called when the App becomes active. They are called if I go to a different screen and back, which actually does show the class file used...

Comment: Weeell, it's pretty dull this Friday :). http://thecodinglove.com/post/128846296935/last-lines-of-code-on-friday

Comment: Actually, due to the debugging difficulty when working with a Watch App (i.e. you can only attach the debugger to the App when loaded) it appears that viewDidLoad is called, but not viewWillAppear. SO now I can register the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewDidLoad procedure was actually called, but the viewDidAppear is not if the App comes form the background. So it is possible to create a notification listener in the viewDidLoad to listen for the application to come out of background mode.